# Creating a container with x-ways x-tensions API (Python)

Tags: python, api, computer-forensics

Maybe someone can help me with creating a container with the x-ways x-tensions API (Python).
I can't find any help on the web. I'm a newbie in scripting with Python (object oriented). I can only create simple functions for reuse.

```
HANDLE XWF_CreateContainer(
   LPWSTR lpFileName,
   DWORD nFlags,
   LPVOID pReserved
);
```

I've tried it p.e. with

```
def XWF_CreateContainer('D:\\test.ctr'):
    return
```

But nothing happens.

Edit:

```
import OutputRedirector
import XWF

# The first function that is called when a Python X-Tension is called
def XT_Init(nVersion, nFlags, hMainWnd, lpReserved):
   OutputRedirector.install()
   print('Hello World')
   return 

# Called just before execution of the Python script concludes
def XT_Done(lpReserved):
   print('Goodbye World')
   return 

def XT_About(hParentWnd, lpReserved):
   print('What I am about? A friendly greeter program!')
   OutputRedirector.install()
   #XWF.CreateContainer('D:\\test.ctr')
   return

#def XWF_CreateContainer(lpFileName, nFlags, pReserved):
   #print('testing CreateContainer')
   #help(nFlags)
   #return

def XWF_CreateContainer('D:\\test.ctr', nFlags, pReserved):
   print('testing CreateContainer')
   help(nFlags)
   return

def XT_Prepare(hVolume, hEvidence, nOpType, lpReserved):
   return

def XT_Finalize(hVolume, hEvidence, nOpType, lpReserved):
   return

def XT_ProcessSearchHit(iSize, nItemID, nRelOfs, nAbsOfs, lpOptionalHitPtr, lpSearchTermID, nLength, nCodePage, nFlags):
   return

def XT_ProcessItem(nItem, reserved):
   return

def XT_ProcessItemEx(nItem, hItem, reserved):
   return
```

I've modified the "Greeter.py" example file.

tried different ways:

XWF.CreateContainer -> AttributeError :  'module' object has no attribute 'CreateContainer'
def XWF_CreateContainer('D:\test.ctr'... -> Failed to execute C:\x-ways Forensics v17.5 Beta 7\Greeter.py: import Greeter

I'm using the 32-bit x-ways Forensics v17.4 SR-6/v17.5 Beta 7 under a 64-bit Windows 7 Professional, with admin-rights.

```
def XT_About(hParentWnd, lpReserved):
   print('What I am about? A friendly greeter program!')
   XWF_CreateContainer('D:\\test.ctr')
   return

def XWF_CreateContainer(lpFileName):
   print('testing CreateContainer')
   return
```

gives me " testing CreateContainer " as output but the file D:\test.ctr wasn't created.

Comment: Yeah this must be one of the functions that doesn't actually work. I ran into that a lot when using their API. Contact X-Ways for more support or create your own container.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** In your updated code, the error is indicating that this is not a valid function. This is likely one of the several that don't work.

[The X-Ways API is decently documented on their website.](http://www.x-ways.net/forensics/x-tensions/api.html) You should definitely read through that first. Also, you will need to understand how to code in object-oriented Python or stop and learn that first.

Next you will need to [download the Python API DLL which is bundled with sample scripts](http://www.x-ways.net/forensics/x-tensions/Python.zip). Admittedly, not all of the sample scripts work well so they are not all good teaching models (and you will find [undocumented functions that I take advantage of in my own script](http://code.google.com/p/digital0day/downloads/detail?name=mapGPSv1.py&can=2&q=#makechanges)). A heuristic approach will make this clear (trial and error), which is how I learned. Note that most of the scripts import OutputRedirector, which means you need to have that file in the same directory as your script (they wrote this script to simplify console output to the message window within X-Ways).

Then you should read the README file that is included with this bundle, which explains a lot about the Python API (I'm not going to explain all the basics since it already does a good job).

Once you've added the correct DLL to your list of X-Tensions in the software (as described in the README file) and included all of the *required* functions, I recommend beginning with a simple test script just to ensure it is working. The Greeter.py script included with the DLL is a great script to use for testing. Use the Skeleton.py as your template for new scripts. You must include all of the functions in that base script.

Beyond that I cannot help you any more without seeing the full code you tried, knowing what version of X-Ways you used (ensuring it is 32-bit), what Windows version you have, what steps you have already taken/tried, what exact output you received, etc. If you read all of the documentation provided by X-Ways and followed their instructions and then tested with their pre-written scripts, you should have little trouble. I suspect you have not RTFM, however ;)